# How to add a Custom EndPointBehavior to the web.config of the service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have followed [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352678/Add-Custom-Message-Header-in-WCF-4-Calls) and have created `MyMessageInspector` and `MyEndPointBehavior` clases as below:

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming request: {0}", request);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }
}

public class MyEndPointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    #region IEndpointBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher;
        if (channelDispatcher != null)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                ed.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

How to add MyEndPointBehavior to the web.config?

I've added the below extensions:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="myMessageInspector" type="MessageInspectorProject.MyEndPointBehavior, MessageInspectorProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

But when I try to use it in below, it complains:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <myMessageInspector/>
```

Its complain is as below:

> Invalid element in configuration. The extension 'myMessageInspector' does not derive from correct extension base type 'System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement'.

How to add `MyEndPointBehavior` to the web.config?

Comment: Great link for what you're trying to do: http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx

Comment: Have you tried using this tag: <endpointBehaviors>

Comment: The error messsage says it all, your custom extension type must inherit from `System.ServiceModel.Configuration.BehaviorExtensionElement`. You can either create a new class, or make `MyMessageInspector` derive from that. You have to override `CreateBehavior()` and `BehaviorType` members. The `BehaviorType` will return `typeof(MyEndPointBehavior)` and `CreateBehavior()` will return an instance of this class.

Answer (score 25):

You have to also create a custom **BehaviorExtensionElement** and use it in web.config file. There are many articles which can help you like these

http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector

https://github.com/geersch/WcfMessageLogging

http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?p=2083

http://trycatch.me/adding-custom-message-headers-to-a-wcf-service-using-inspectors-behaviors/

Anyway fix your code to this way

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incoming request: {0}", request);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }
}

public class MyEndPointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    #region IEndpointBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher;
        if (channelDispatcher != null)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher ed in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                ed.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyMessageInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here add new BehaviorExtensionElement

```
public class CustomBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new MyEndPointBehavior();
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(MyEndPointBehavior);
        }
    }
}
```

And update your web.config

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="myMessageInspector" type="MessageInspectorProject.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, MessageInspectorProject"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <myMessageInspector />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: When this is done one get intellisense errors on the new "myMessageInspector" element when using it in web.config. Is there a way to make intellisense accept the new BehaviorExtensionElement/myMessageInspector?

Answer (score 0):

for me was enough to remove the version of assembly in the web.config

```
Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```